# create spreadsheet programmatically in android studio

Tags: android, google-apps-script, google-sheets, oauth, android-studio-3.0

I want to create a spreadsheet programmatically in android studio. how can I do that?
I used OAuth for signing in the user and now wants to create the spreadsheet in his drive folder.

I found the below code but don't know how to use it...

```
Spreadsheet spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet()
    .setProperties(new SpreadsheetProperties()
    .setTitle(title));
spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets().create(spreadsheet)
    .setFields("spreadsheetId")
    .execute();
System.out.println("Spreadsheet ID: " + spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetId());
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For creating a Google Sheet in a programmatic way you should try to use [Sheet API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api). More specifcally you need to use the [`create`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create#examples_1) method.

If you are using the Google libraries for Java you could just try to follow the example in the `create` endpoint:

```java
/*
 * BEFORE RUNNING:
 * ---------------
 * 1. If not already done, enable the Google Sheets API
 *    and check the quota for your project at
 *    https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets
 * 2. Install the Java client library on Maven or Gradle. Check installation
 *    instructions at https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client.
 *    On other build systems, you can add the jar files to your project from
 *    https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/sheets/v4/java
 */
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.Spreadsheet;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;

public class SheetsExample {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    // TODO: Assign values to desired fields of `requestBody`:
    Spreadsheet requestBody = new Spreadsheet();

    Sheets sheetsService = createSheetsService();
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Create request = sheetsService.spreadsheets().create(requestBody);

    Spreadsheet response = request.execute();

    // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
    System.out.println(response);
  }

  public static Sheets createSheetsService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    // TODO: Change placeholder below to generate authentication credentials. See
    // https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/java#step_3_set_up_the_sample
    //
    // Authorize using one of the following scopes:
    //   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
    //   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"
    //   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
    GoogleCredential credential = null;

    return new Sheets.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName("Google-SheetsSample/0.1")
        .build();
  }
}
```

*This example is not handling credentials and you will need to change this in order to work*

In case you need more information in the libraries read through the [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java) to work from there, also look at the java [`create` method](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/Sheets.Spreadsheets.html#create-com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.Spreadsheet-). And of course you can just do an HTTP request if you have already managed all the OAuth part.